# Rails: Why am I logged out after form submission? (short)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am creating a app for picture uploading. There are users, albums, pics. However, when I log in and create a new album, on the redirect it logs me out for some reason. Can anyone help?

Here's my Albums controller create action

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  @album.users << @user.friends.find(params[:users][:friend_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to user_album_path(@user, @album), notice: 'Album was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @album, status: :created, location: @album}
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @album.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end 
end
```

config/routes

```
Pholder::Application.routes.draw do
resources :users do
  resources :friends
  resources :albums do
    resources :photos
  end
end
end
```

(don't think this is necessary, but here's the form for album/new.html.erb in case you want to see)

```
<%= form_for ([@user, @album]), :html => { :id => "uploadform", :multipart => true } do |f| %>
<div class="formholder">
    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= collection_select(:users, :friend_id, @user.friends, :id, :name_with_initial, :multiple => true ) %>

    <%= f.label :description %>
    <%= f.text_area :description %>

    <br>

    <%=f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

html generated form:

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/users/27/albums" class="new_album" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="uploadform" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cUx2AZc5Cxa+FZxtOWwHDZ8WSnvb4l9B2BqcWhXYmgg=" /></div>
<div class="formholder">
<label for="album_name">Name</label>
<input id="album_name" name="album[name]" size="30" type="text" />

<select id="users_friend_id" name="users[friend_id]"><option value="29">Ben</option>
<option value="30">Bally</option></select>

<label for="album_description">Description</label>
<textarea cols="40" id="album_description" name="album[description]" rows="20">
 </textarea>

<br>

<input name="commit" type="submit" value="Create Album" />
```

terminal log

```
Started POST "/users/27/albums" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-10-08 18:51:11 -0400
Processing by AlbumsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cUx2AZc5Cxa+FZxtOWwHDZ8WSnvb4l9B2BqcWhXYmgg=", "album"=>{"name"=>"world tour", "description"=>"fadsjkafsdjk"}, "users"=>{"friend_id"=>"29"}, "commit"=>"Create Album", "user_id"=>"27"}
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", "27"]]
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "users"."id" = "friendships"."friend_id" WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = 27 AND "users"."id" = ? AND (status = 'accepted') LIMIT 1  [["id", "29"]]
   (0.0ms)  begin transaction
   (0.7ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = '0lIsogcOIkUMMWFbRWerjw', "updated_at" = '2012-10-08 22:51:11.476530' WHERE "users"."id" = 27
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "albums" ("created_at", "description", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00], ["description", "fadsjkafsdjk"], ["name", "world tour"], ["updated_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "album_users" ("album_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["album_id", 113], ["created_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 29]]
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "album_users" ("album_id", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["album_id", 113], ["created_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Mon, 08 Oct 2012 22:51:11 UTC +00:00], ["user_id", 27]]
   (6.3ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/27/albums/113
```

Comment: Can you check if the HTML generated form contains the <input name="authenticity_token" /> ? form_for is supposed to create that for you, but I already faced the problem when people where getting disconnected because of the authenticity_token was missing.

Comment: ok give me a sec i'll go check

Comment: i added the code for the html generated form. seems like it's not in there... would you know how to add it?

Comment: as described here http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html this should be added for you when using form_for, that's weird ...

Comment: can you paste the part you are talking about? the link sent me to a long website

Comment: The authenticity token is in your form, check the first line, it's at the end : <input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cUx2AZc5Cxa+FZxtOWwHDZ8WSnvb4l9B2BqcWhXYmgg=" /> So if the token is present, I have no idea what could be the cause of your disconnection. Sorry

Comment: could it be because the remember token is being changed for some reason? I uploaded my terminal log and there's a line where it updates the remember token

Comment: might be the remember token. what are you using for user authentication?

Comment: @randomtaiwanese hey. I think I'm just using something handmade, since this is my first project and I wanted to learn. Here's my code on github: https://github.com/EdmundMai/railstest

Comment: Could you please update the answer with exactly what was wrong and how you fixed it? There is 2 threads of comments which makes it longer and unclear to reach the solution that worked for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at your code (link is in your comment below), here is the problem. When saving the album, you are calling @user.save! This is triggering the create_remember_token in the user model, which is causing the logout.

Here is your code calling @user.save in the album controller:

```
def create
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @album = @user.albums.build(params[:album])
  @album.users << @user.friends.find(params[:users][:friend_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    if @user.save
```

Here is the before_save in the user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  ....
  before_save :create_remember_token
```

You might want to eliminate the before_save and then just call create_remember_token when the user logs in.

Comment: sorry about that. I actually already had that in my app... so I don't think it'll solve the problem...

Comment: Actually, now that I scrolled all the way to the right in the generated html, I see that the authenticity_token field is present. So something else is going on.

Comment: I'm looking through the log in my terminal... could it be the `UPDATE "users" SET "remember_token" = '0lIsogcOIkUMMWFbRWerjw', "updated_at" = '2012-10-08 22:51:11.476530' WHERE "users"."id" = 27` line? It looks like it's UPDATEing the remember_token. should it not be doing that since the user is logged in already? I added the terminal log to my question

Comment: What authentication system are you using? Something like Devise, or AuthLogic, or did you create your own?

Comment: is there a way to check? since this is my first project I tried to stay away from any gems and try to learn it myself, so it's probably something handmade... here's my code on github: https://github.com/EdmundMai/railstest

Comment: yeh I think so too. I have my whole directory up on github: https://github.com/EdmundMai/railstest so you can look there. Which folder would I look at to look up authentication?

Comment: IT WORKS!!!! thanks a lot!!! I was also suspicious of the @user.save... However, since I removed the before_save line, will a remember_token still be made anywhere else? I thought I needed a remember token for sessions? Won't removing that line screw it up (the app works without it, I'm just not understanding why)

Comment: You will need to call create_remember_token manually. Probably the best place is SessionsHelper at the top of both sign_in and sign_out.